# Is this reliable for device-independent window splitting in HTML/CSS/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, window

The code offered here works very well in chrome, safari, and an android browser.
I think it may not be fully invariant across all modern browsers.
I ask for scrutiny to harden this into fully reliable across most browsers.

My eventual goal is to turn this into a foundation for a
character-at-a-time chat app where the current user is always the bottom window
and the top window is the person with whom you are chatting.

I have used two Shakespeare sonnets as content to illustrate
how the window behaves when it is first loaded and then resized
both to very small and full-width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="even window split" />
  <meta name="description" content="even window split and scrolling content" />
  <title>even window split and scrolling content</title>
  <style>
div  { border-collapse:collapse; }
body { background-color:saddlebrown; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function hDoc(f) { return f.toString().replace(/.*\/\*([^\*]*).\/.*/, '$1');  }

labelA = hDoc(function() {/* Shakespeare sonnet CXVI: */});
verseA = hDoc(function() {/* <pre>
Let me not to the marriage of true minds
Admit impediments. Love is not love
Which alters when it alteration finds,
Or bends with the remover to remove:
O, no! it is an ever-fixed mark,
That looks on tempests and is never shaken;
It is the star to every wandering bark,
Whose worth's unknown, although his height be taken.
Love's not Time's fool, though rosy lips and cheeks
Within his bending sickle's compass come;
Love alters not with his brief hours and weeks,
But bears it out even to the edge of doom.
  If this be error and upon me proved,
  I never writ, nor no man ever loved.
</pre> */});

labelB = hDoc(function() {/* Shakespeare sonnet CX: */});
verseB = hDoc(function() {/* <pre>
Alas! 'tis true, I have gone here and there,
And made my self a motley to the view,
Gored mine own thoughts, sold cheap what is most dear,
Made old offences of affections new;
Most true it is, that I have looked on truth
Askance and strangely; but, by all above,
These blenches gave my heart another youth,
And worse essays proved thee my best of love.
Now all is done, have what shall have no end:
Mine appetite I never more will grind
On newer proof, to try an older friend,
A god in love, to whom I am confined.
  Then give me welcome, next my heaven the best,
  Even to thy pure and most most loving breast.
</pre> */});

function resize() {
  var w  = window.innerWidth      , h  = window.innerHeight;
  var h2 = Math.round(h/2 -    2) , ht = 8;
  var ww = Math.round(w -      2) , hh = Math.round(h2-ht-   2);
  var ut = Math.round(   ht+   2) , ub = Math.round(ut+hh     );
  var lt = Math.round(ub+ht+   2) , lb = h;
  var black = '000'               , white = 'FFF';

  style0  = 'div { overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom: 1px; }\n';
  styleA  = '#verseA{';
  styleA +=     'border:'                    + '1px solid black;';
  styleA +=     'width:'             + ww    + 'px;'             ;
  styleA +=     'height:'            + hh    + 'px;'             ;
  styleA +=     'position:'                  + 'absolute;'       ;
  styleA +=     'top:'               + ut    + 'px;'             ;
  styleA +=     'bottom:'            + ub    + 'px;'             ;
  styleA +=     'left:'                      + '0px;'            ;
  styleA +=     'right:'                     + '0px;'            ;
  styleA +=     'background-color:#' + black + ';'               ;
  styleA +=     'color:#'            + white + ';'               ;
  styleA += '}\n';
  styleB  = '#verseB{';
  styleB +=     'border:'                    + '1px solid black;';
  styleB +=     'width:'             + ww    + 'px;'             ;
  styleB +=     'height:'            + hh    + 'px;'             ;
  styleB +=     'position:'                  + 'absolute;'       ;
  styleB +=     'top:'               + lt    + 'px;'             ;
  styleB +=     'bottom:'            + lb    + 'px;'             ;
  styleB +=     'left:'                      + '0px;'            ;
  styleB +=     'right:'                     + '0px;'            ;
  styleB +=     'background-color:#' + white + ';'               ;
  styleB +=     'color:#'            + black + ';'               ;
  styleB += '}\n';

  shown0  = '<style type="text/css">\n'+ style0 + styleA + styleB +'</style>';
  shownA  = '\n<div id="verseA"><pre>';
  shownA += '\n<div id="headerA"><b id="labelA">' + labelA + '</b></div>\n';
  shownA += verseA;
  shownA += '\n</pre></div>';
  shownB  = '\n<div id="verseB"><pre>';
  shownB += '\n<div id="headerA"><b id="labelA">' + labelB + '</b></div>\n';
  shownB += verseB;
  shownB += '\n</pre></div>\n';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = shown0 + shownA + shownB;
}
window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
  </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="resize()" onResize="resize()"><div id="demo"></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is wrong with 50vh and 50vw ?

Comment: Thank you for the introduction to the viewport units.  I had to use:
var h0 = 0, h1 = 49.5, h2 = 99.0, w0 = 0, w1 = 49.8, w2 = 99.6;
This is because 50 and 100 force both horizontal and vertical scroll bars to appear.  Also, this approach always leaves a wider bottom and right margin when the window is increased to a large size.  Nevertheless, I think your answer with my mods will be the most reliable across devices.

Comment: I reverted to px instead of vh/vw because of broader support (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/) but I simplified it more and put the code I am currently using up on github (https://github.com/jlettvin/unchat) for which the first prototype test is available here (http://rawgit.com/jlettvin/unchat/master/splitwindow.html).